# setInterval keeps speeding up

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval

New to Stack and new, more or less, to JS and React (trying to go through a free coding bootcamp).

Anyways, I'm working on doing a Pomodoro clock and am using setInterval for the countdown.

Hitting the play/pause button changes the state and starts the countdown timer. Hitting it again, pauses it (pausing works just fine). But starting the clock UP again, it considerably speeds up, as if by hitting the play button, it changes the interval in setInterval, almost to the point where it counts down by one as normal then speeds up, counts down as normal, then speeds up again. I'm not sure where it's going wrong or how this is being caused. Any help is appreciated.

```
 startStop(){
    this.changeState();
    this.startClock();
  }

  changeState(){
    if (this.state.timer_Running == true){
      this.setState({timer_Running: false})
    } else {
      this.setState({timer_Running: true})
    }
  }

  startClock() {
    this.setState({timer_State: setInterval(this.timerFunc, 1000)}); //Sets the interval at 1000ms or 1 second
  }

  timerFunc() { 
    if (this.state.timer_Running == true) { //Timer running is a state set to false so that when the play/pause button is hit, it switches to true and then the timer then begins.
      if (this.state.timer_Sec == 0) {
        this.setState({
          timer_Sec: 10, 
          timer_Min: this.state.timer_Min - 1
        });
      }
      if (this.state.timer_Sec > 0) {
        this.setState({timer_Sec: this.state.timer_Sec - 1})
      }
      if (this.state.timer_Min <= 0 && this.state.timer_Sec == 0) {
        //Need to change this to make sure that it then adds in break to replace session and start that timer.
        this.stopClock();  
      }
    } else{
      this.stopClock();
    }
  }


  stopClock() {
    clearInterval(this.state.timer_State);
  }
```

Comment: you're probably starting more than one interval at a time

Comment: You need to call `clearInterval` on the previous interval before starting a new one.

Comment: `startStop()` if called multiple times will just start numerous intervals on the clock. it needs to call `stopClock()` before calling `startClock()` again.

Comment: Could be how React handles state.  Don't think `clearInterval(this.state.timer_State);` will work.  Does it work if you do `this.timer_State = setInterval(this.timerFunc, 1000)}` and `clearInterval(this.timer_State);` instead?

Comment: @Klaycon That solution made the most sense to me and seems to have solved my problem. I simply added a call to clearInterval() in my startStop function and it seemed to have solved it. Thanks!